# sending port via router port not opening and how to access a computer/server externally using router's ip address?

Tags: networking

Hi I am trying to make my router(TPlink router) to forward port by configuring it and by creating NAT virtual server or port triggering. Firstly the port doesn't open which I have checked via an online website, the port is closed. Secondly if the port does open, would I be able to access my computer or computer server or a website hosted on my wamp server externally via another network from some other place externally? I am not sure what are the things on my computer that I would  be able to access from outside? How exactly am I going to do it? I am aware that I am going to use my router external ip address which I know and the port that I have associated with the ip address of the computer I am trying to access. I  am just a beginner but I am really into networking. Can somebody explain the entire process please?

Comment: This is a fairly good enough question, but needs to be put on, maybe, serverfault.com. Flagging this for migration.

Comment: Hi there, man I am a little frustrated just now, I spent hours today on this without even a hint of progress, I am not attending any university or course to study networking, I am just trying to learn it on my own. It would be great if instead of flagging it for migration, you could have answered it briefly, as a professional courtesy

Comment: If I knew the answer, I would have given it here and then flagged this question for migration.

Answer (score 1):

Your local host can be accessed from anywhere in the world.
Just use put the ip of the pc/wamp server installed pc in the DMZ Box under Forward Menu of your tp-link router & enable DMZ option.